# Parser in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I am trying to find the parser in Caffe. By parser, I mean the part of the code that reads the network configuration from a file and parses it. I was wondering if anyone knows where in the Caffe codebase I should look for this specific piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffe's text file format for specifying models uses the [Google Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en) format.

You can see the code that reads a model in [src/caffe/util/io.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/fc77ef3d23423e57d83e16c32844bbbe8d4d9f0c/src/caffe/util/io.cpp#L32):

```
bool ReadProtoFromTextFile(const char* filename, Message* proto) {
  int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
  CHECK_NE(fd, -1) << "File not found: " << filename;
  FileInputStream* input = new FileInputStream(fd);
  bool success = google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parse(input, proto);
  delete input;
  close(fd);
  return success;
}
```

Try using GitHub's search to see places in the code that call this function.